# Carmichael numbers algorithm sanjoy das gupta

Tags: algorithm, cryptography

I am reading Carmichael numbers in Algorithms book by Sanjoy das gupta at followinglink page 38

http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~naveen/courses/CSL630/all.pdf

Carmichael numbers
The smallest Carmichael number is 561. It is not a prime: 561 = 3*11* 17; yet it fools the Fermat test, There is a way around Carmichael numbers, using a slightly more refined primality test due to Rabin and Miller. Write N - 1 in the form 2^t * u. As before we'll choose a random base a and check the value of a ^N-1 mod N. Perform this computation by first determining a^u mod N and then repeatedly squaring, to get the sequence:

```
a^u mod N; a^2u mod N; : : : ; a^2tu = a^N-1 mod N:
```

If a^N-1 not equal to 1 mod N, then N is composite by Fermat's little theorem, and we're done.

But if a^N-1 is equal to 1 mod N, we conduct a little follow-up test: somewhere in the preceding sequence, we
ran into a 1 for the first time. If this happened after the first position (that is, if a^u mod N is not equal to
1), and if the preceding value in the list is not -1 mod N, then we declare N composite.

In the latter case, we have found a nontrivial square root of 1 modulo N: a number that
is not 1 mod N but that when squared is equal to 1 mod N. Such a number can only exist
if N is composite. It turns out that if we combine this square-root check with
our earlier Fermat test, then at least three-fourths of the possible values of a between 1 and
N - 1 will reveal a composite N, even if it is a Carmichael number.

Following questions on above text.

Question 1:

I am not able to follow below text

> But if a^N-1 is equal to 1 mod N, we conduct a little follow-up test:
>   somewhere in the preceding sequence, we ran into a 1 for the first
>   time. If this happened after the first position (that is, if a^u mod N
>   is not equal to 1), and if the preceding value in the list is not -1
>   mod N, then we declare N composite.

What does above statement mean? Any example will help.

Question 2:

What does author talking about square root here in last paragraph first two lines?

Thanks

Comment: And this relates to programming... how?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/